# getActivity() in fragment is null after orientation change

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, orientation, fragment

I have a problem with startActivityForResult, fragments and orientation changes.

I call startActivityForResult() from one fragment, then I open second activity with fragment attached. In this second activity when I change orientation and go back to the first activity then onActivityResult (fragment method) is called. But there's a problem, because a I have something like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    getActivity(); //here's a problem because 
    //getActivity is null but only after orientation change on second activity 
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All the problem was that I don't declare android:id for the fragment in XML. Android need's ID or TAG to recognize stored fragment and reproduce all element's in it. So guys, remeber - every instance of fragment need unique id or tag!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the required super before calling getActivity(), like so:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    getActivity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved for me:

```
private Activity activity;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    this.activity = getActivity();
}
```

and use this activity anywhere in the fragment that you need.